# linq query for selecting from one list based on another

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

```
public class Test
{
  int i;
  string s;
}

List<Test> testList = new List<Test>(); //assume there are some values in it.

List<int> intList = new List<int>(){ 1,2,3};
```

How to I say get `items from testList where i is in intList` using the linq to objects.

something like `List<Test> testIntList = testList.Where(t=>t.i in intList)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, it would be:

```
List<Test> testIntList = testList.Where(t => intList.Contains(t.i)).ToList();
```

However, that might be slow if `intList` is large, since `List<T>.Contains` performs its search in O(n). A faster approach would be to use a `HashSet<T>`:

```
HashSet<int> intList = new HashSet<int>(){ 1,2,3 };
```

Answer (score 2):

This would also be interesting and would perform well:

```
List<test> finalList = testList.Join(intList, 
                                     test => test.id,
                                     i => i,
                                     (t, i) => t).ToList();
```

You know when you join tables in a SQL `SELECT`? This is how to do it using Linq to Objects.

Comment: i'm not sure if i understood this right. how does this know what i => i is in this particular query. its not defined anywhere.

Comment: @Alex J - The expression `i => i` is a lambda expression that is it's own definition. In this query it says the the join uses the values from `intList`.